Evaluate a hard integral: $\int_{t'=0}^{\infty} (\alpha+\beta t')^{\gamma-1}\left(1-e^{-k(t'-t_{0})}\right)e^{-(r-g)(t'-t_{0})} \, \mathrm{d}t'$
I'm a postdoc working through a paper (Drivers of peak warming in a
consumption-maximizing world by Myers R. Allen), and trying to get from their equation $(8)$ to their equation $(9)$; no explanation of the solution is provided.
Their equation $(8)$ is
$$
\text{SCC}_t = \gamma W_t D_0 T_{\text{TCRE}} \int_{t'=0}^\infty (T_t + T't')^{\gamma-1} (1-e^{-k_s t'}) e^{-(r-g)t'} \, \mathrm{d}t'
$$
and their solution in equation $(9)$ assumes $T'/T_t \ll r-g$ and they claim this yields
$$\begin{align*}
\text{SCC}_t& = \gamma W_t D_0 T_{\text{TCRE}} T_t^{\gamma-1} \left[ \left( \frac{1}{r-g} + \frac{1}{k_s+r-g} \right)  \right. \\
&\qquad \left. + \frac{(\gamma-1) T'}{T_t} \left( \frac{1}{(r-g)^2} - \frac{1}{(k_s+r-g)^2} \right) \right]
\end{align*}$$
In its essence, the integral I'm concerned with is thus of the form:
$$
I = \int_{t'=0}^{\infty} \left(\alpha+\beta t'\right)^{\gamma-1}\left(1-e^{-k(t'-t_{0})}\right)e^{-(r-g)(t'-t_{0})} \, \mathrm{d}t'
$$
where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $k$, $r$, $g$ and $t_{0}$ are constants and the integral is over dummy variable $t'$.
I did this integral a few years back, but lost my notes for it and now am trying to revisit the material - if anyone fancies a challenge I would be happy to have the assistance.
EDIT: I have now fixed a lot of typos, hope that helps.

It would be helpful to provide the solution since the article is behind a paywall...

Start by recognizing it’s a convolution. Think Laplace …

The key point is that assumption $\frac{T'}{T_t}\ll r-g$. With this, note that $$(T_t+T't')^{\gamma-1} = T_t^{\gamma-1} \left(1 + (\gamma-1) \frac{T'}{T_t}t' + \dots \right),$$ and now they just keep the leading order.
Using the integrals $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-ax}\text{d}x = \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}}$ we then find ($a=r-g$, $b=k_s+r-g$ and $c=\frac{T'}{T_t}$)
$$I = \int_0^\infty (1 + (\gamma-1) c t')\left(e^{-at'} - e^{-bt'}\right) \text{d}t' = \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} + (\gamma-1)c \left[ \frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{b^2} \right].$$
I leave unraveling the mess of constants to someone else, but this is the gist of it.
I'll also assume the missing minus sign in the second term is a typo in the question, but other than that this is exactly equivalent to the claimed result.

This is great, thank you!

There's nothing difficult about this integral.  Assuming $r - g > 0$ and $k+r-g  > 0$, it converges to
$$ \frac{\left(-\alpha  g +\alpha  k +\alpha  r +\beta \right) {\mathrm e}^{ \left(k+r-g \right) t_0}}{\left(k+r-g \right)^{2}}-\frac{ \left(\alpha  g -\alpha  r -\beta \right){\mathrm e}^{\left(r -g \right) {t_0}}}{\left(r -g \right)^{2}}$$
EDIT: With the typos corrected, you need to integrate using the incomplete Gamma function.  Assuming $\alpha, \beta > 0$, and again $r - g > 0$ and $k + r - g > 0$, the result is
$$\beta^{\gamma -1} {\mathrm e}^{-\frac{\left(-r +g \right) \left(\beta   t_{0}+\alpha   \right)}{\beta }} \left(-\left(-g +k +r \right)^{-\gamma} \Gamma \! \left(\gamma , \frac{\alpha   \left(-g +k +r \right)}{\beta }\right) {\mathrm e}^{k \left(t_{0}+\frac{\alpha }{\beta }\right)}+\left(r -g \right)^{-\gamma} \Gamma \! \left(\gamma , \frac{\left(r -g \right) \alpha  }{\beta }\right)\right)
$$

Apologies, there was a typo in the original post. The integral should have a $(\alpha + \beta t')^{\gamma-1}$, not $(\alpha + \beta t')$. This is what makes it tricky, at least for me.

Maybe it can be added how the formula that it converges to was found?

@ТymaGaidash, I agree - it's not very helpful at the moment. Also, there is no reference to the incomplete gamma function in the paper's final result, so even if the incomplete gamma function result is correct then I assume I need to take some limit of it to get the paper's result?

For my ease of mind, I will start by letting $\newcommand{\r}{\rho}
\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\b}{\beta}
\newcommand{\t}{\tau}
\newcommand{\k}{\kappa}
\r := r-g$ and $\t := t'-t_0$ to give us
$$\begin{align*}
I &:= \int_{t'=0}^{\infty} \left(\alpha+\beta t'\right)\left(1+e^{-k(t'-t_{0})}\right)e^{-(r-g)(t'-t_{0})} dt'\\
&= \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} \left(\alpha+\beta (\t+t_0) \right)
    \left(1+e^{-k\t}\right)e^{-\r \t} d\t 
\end{align*}$$
We then distribute the exponential inside the $1+e^{-k\t}$ term:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} \left(\alpha+\beta (\t+t_0) \right)
    \left(e^{-\r\t} +e^{-(k+\r) \t}\right)  d\t\\
 &= \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} \left(\alpha+\beta (\t+t_0) \right)
    \left(e^{-\r\t} +e^{\k \t}\right)  d\t
\end{align*}
$$
where, once again for my sanity, I've defined a new constant $\k := -(k+\r)$. Then we distribute and apply linearity:
$$
I = \a \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} e^{-\r t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+\a \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} e^{\k \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+ \b \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} (\t+t_0) e^{-\r \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+ \b \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} (\t+t_0) e^{\k \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
$$
Inverting the substitution on the latter two we more precisely have
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \a \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} e^{-\r \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+\a \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} e^{\k \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+ \b \int_{\t=0}^{\infty} \t e^{-\r (\t-t_0)} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+ \b \int_{\t=0}^{\infty} \t e^{\k (\t-t_0)} \, \mathrm{d}\t\\
&= \a \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} e^{-\r \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+\a \int_{\t=-t_0}^{\infty} e^{\k \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+ \b e^{\r t_0} \int_{\t=0}^{\infty} \t e^{-\r \t)} \, \mathrm{d}\t
+ \b e^{-\k t_0} \int_{\t=0}^{\infty} \t e^{\k \t} \, \mathrm{d}\t
\end{align*}$$
The latter two integrals are easily calculated via integration by parts, and the former two are elementary ones. Noting that
$$
\int x e^{\gamma x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \left( \frac x\gamma - \frac{1}{\gamma^2} \right) e^{\gamma x}
$$
we see integrals of the type $\int_{x_0}^\infty xe^{\gamma x} \, \mathrm{d}x$ (for constant $\gamma$) converge provided $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\gamma x}$ exists, namely when $\gamma \le 0$. This then allows us to discuss the convergence of $I$: we require:

$\r := r-g \ge 0$ (first & third integrals)
$\k := -(k+\r) \le 0$ (second & fourth integrals)
In particular, then,
$$
0 \le k+\r = k+r-g
$$
so in turn we require $k \ge 0$ as well as $r-g \ge 0$.


As noted in the comments, if
$$\begin{align*}
f(t') &:= \alpha + \b t' \\
g(t') &:= (1 + e^{kt'}) e^{(r-g)t'}
\end{align*}$$
(be mindful of the signs!) then one may also examine $I$ through the lens of convolution, as if
$$
(F \ast G)(t_\ast) := \int_0^\infty F(t') G(t_\ast - t') \, \mathrm{d}t'
$$
then
$$
I = (f \ast g)(t_0)
$$

Returning to concerns of the value of $I$ under the aforementioned convergence conditions, we get vanishing as $\t \to \infty$ and so (after some mild simplification)
$$
I = \frac{a}{\r} e^{\r t_0}
- \frac{\a}{\k} e^{-\k t_0}
+ \frac{\b e^{\r t_0} }{\r^2} 
+ \frac{\b e^{-\k t_0} }{\k^2} 
$$
or, returning to the definitions of $\k,\r$,
$$
I = \frac{\a}{r-g} e^{(r-g) t_0}
+ \frac{\a}{k+r-g} e^{(k+r-g) t_0}
+ \frac{\b }{(r-g)^2}  e^{(r-g) t_0}
+ \frac{\b }{(k+r-g)^2}  e^{-(k+r-g) t_0}
$$
The paper considers a scenario in which $\b/\a \gg r-g$. Why, I don't know; the wording of the paper seems to suggest it is more a concern of the application and context the integral comes from, and not one of convergence, however.

Quote: For relatively slow rates of warming, such that $T'/T_t \ll r-g$ (necessarily the case in all but the most aggressive geoengineering scenarios as temperatures approach their peak), this gives...
Note that the paper has $T'$ and $T_t$ where OP has $\beta$ and $\a$, respectively.

It seems, aside from some stray constants (and in particular, a stray parameter $\gamma$ which you seem to be assuming equal to $2$ if you didn't overlook it, and a sign change in the integrand: they have $1+e^{-k(t'-t_0)}$ instead), their answer is identical to mine, so I'm not sure what that assumption does (unless it's more relevant for $\gamma \ne 2$ or just commentary on the application in general).

Sorry about this, but I had a typo in my post. The integrand should have $(\alpha + \beta t')^{\gamma-1}$, not $(\alpha + \beta t')$. Basically I wasn't assuming $\gamma=2$, I just made a typo.

It's the $(...)^{\gamma-1}$ that makes this difficult for me.

Their solution is also now provided in the post, that's what I'm aiming for.
